# HugginFace Transformers implementation of Bark Model: Getting the Fine Tokens

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-to-speech, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I would need some help to get the fine tokens from the output of the BarkFineModel (see https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.32.1/model_doc/bark#transformers.BarkFineModel) I cannot get it to work. I got to tokenizer -> semantic_model -> semantic_tokens -> coarse_tokens -> fine_model ... fails with a

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("suno/bark-small")
inputs = tokenizer("some text prompt")
tokenizer_input_ids_tensor = inputs['input_ids'][:,0]
semantic_tokens = semantic_model.forward(tokenizer_input_ids_tensor)
coarse_tokens = coarse_model(tokenizer_input_ids_tensor)
coarse_input_ids = torch.tensor(coarse_tokens['logits'].unsqueeze(-1)).to(torch.long)
fine_tokens = fine_model(codebook_idx=1, input_ids=coarse_input_ids) # this fails !
```

Would anyone try to understand by what is needed by the HugginFace documentation to make the BarkFineModel forward method. I am deeply stuck here... Any help would be very appreciated !